# Are there some penalties or drawbacks for having declined flags?

Tags: support, flagging

I'd like to know of there are some penalties or some other kind of drawback for having declined flags.

I ask this because when I find something in questions or answers that I consider to be worthy of moderator attention, I don't refrain myself from flagging it (naturally, I don't want to act like a sort of policeman, I try to use and not abuse this feature).

Of course, sometimes these flags are accepted, some others my own judgement is different from the moderator's and they are declined; this his my [flagging history](https://superuser.com/users/flag-summary/170331).

Comment: FYI, your flagging history is only viewable to moderators.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Penalties, yes - if a large portion of your flags are declined, your flags will eventually be suppressed and never show up in the flag queue available to us Moderators.

Flag suppression is a rather extreme case, and you shouldn't worry about the odd flag being declined.

Comment: Very well, so I can keep trying to improve the site without worrying about finding an angry mob with clubs and torches at my door ;)

Comment: @Sekhemty please do :) we will contact you as a warning, if you've been flagging incorrectly

Comment: @Sekhemty that's what Trogdor is for.  He does all of our burnination of bad posts and users :P